# Are there multiple ways to hash RSA key fingerprints from the same public key?

Tags: ssh-host-key

I am troubleshooting an SFTP upload script on a device in the field. The script worked previously, but now gets a different host key fingerprint when it tries to connect. There should have been no changes to the system that would trigger this, except potentially a Windows update.

My server's RSA2 key fingerprint is

```
ssh-rsa 3072 d9:6c:...
```

The fingerprint from the RSA2 key the device is receiving is

```
ssh-rsa 1024 92:d4:...
```

I know there are different types of host keys (RSA vs DSA vs ECDSA vs ...). Are there also different methods/algorithms to hash a host key that would produce different fingerprints based on the algo? In other words, is it possible these two fingerprints are legitimately from the same server/key, and the client simply interprets them differently?

Comment: These look like different keys - one 3072 bit key size and the other 1024 bit. Obviously the host key was changed.

Comment: That's what I thought as well, thanks for confirming.

Comment: To answer as asked, over time OpenSSH (and things copying it like PuTTY, WinSCP, FileZilla) has used two different key-fingerprint schemes: older versions use(d) MD5 of the key blob represented in hex with colons (apparently what you have), and 6.8 up normally use SHA256 of the blob represented in base64 but can select the old scheme (`ssh -o FingerprintHash=md5` or `ssh-keygen -l -E md5 [-f file]`). But as @Steffen says yours are clearly different keys, not different fingerprint methods. Have there been changes in the _network_ like a WAF, IDS/IPS, proxy, VPN, etc?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 That's what I'm suspecting. Unfortunately, it's not my network so I don't have those kinds of details.